# Python 2.6 font/colour change + error window

Tags: python, fonts, colors, window, tkinter

I just have two hopefully quick questions.
I'm using Python 2.6

1. How should I go about changing the font and colour of a string with the tkfont class? I seem to find tonnes of documentation about the different functions the tkfont class has, e.g. I think I should be using the tkfont.config(), and what to specify as the options, but nothing on how to apply it.
   e.g. if I wanted to make the string, 'Hello world' be the colour = blue, family = Courier and size = 15, how would I do that with tkfont?
2. Is there a generic python error window that can be called with a windows error sound, etc. Despite me asking for tkfont in the previous question, I'm fairly sure that I shouldn't do this part with tkinter and get the feeling that there's some default python error window that can be called.

Sorry for these pretty nooby questions, I'm really stuck here.

Comment: Strings do not have fonts or colors. Widgets do, though. Can you be more specific about what widgets you are using?

Comment: Oh, sorry, my mistake. Basically, I'm inserting a string into a listbox. I need to specify the font, colour and size of the text based on different conditions.

Edit: Oh and thank you so much for the Standard Dialog bit, I don't know how I missed that!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tkinter comes with many stantard dialogs. A good point of reference for these is the [Standard Dialogs](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-standard-dialogs.htm) page on effbot.

I'll answer your question about colors when you clarify it a little.

Comment: Thanks again for the Standard Dialogs link, I managed to get the rest on my own.
I just used:
my_font = tkFont.Font(family = 'Courier', size = 15)
listbox.config(..., font = my_font)

as for the colour bit, i just used:
listbox.itemconfig(index, fg = 'blue') 
on the items that i needed